# How to have a MySQL procedure return a boolean?

Tags: asp.net, mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I want to create a procedure that takes in a string, searches the table and the specified column for that string, and returns a 1 if it finds it and a zero if it does not.  I am relatively new to SQL and do not know the syntax or commands very well.  I want something like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.GetUsername

(
@Username   NCHAR(10)
)

AS   
    @boolVariable
SELECT  @Username FROM Accounts  
RETURN  @boolVariable
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't return a value, but instead supply that in a result set.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetUsername
(
   @Username   NCHAR(10)
)    
AS       
    SELECT Username FROM Accounts WHERE Username = @UserName;
```

In your calling code, simply check for the existence of a row in the result set.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you're looking for mysql or mssql solution.

```
delimiter //
drop procedure if exists search_string //
create procedure search_string (in str varchar(100))
begin
declare b,r bool;
select count(*) into r from your_table where your_field = str;
if r > 0 then
set b = 1;
else 
set b = 0;
end if;
select b;
end; //
delimiter //

call search_string('searched_string');
```